# Adding value to integer in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, integer

How do I add +1 value to an integer?

Something like

```
Do
    If myClientMachineIP.AddressFamily = Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
        Label2.Text = myClientMachineIP.ToString()
    Else
        TextBox2.Text = "IP is not equal to IPv4"
        proov = +1
        TextBox3.Text = proov
    End If
Loop Until proov = 10
```

How do I add +1 to the `proov` integer variable?

Comment: `proov++` is the simplest way.   You could also do `proov = proov + 1` or `proov += 1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**CORRECTION**

VB.NET does not have the increment operator (`++`), so the simplest way would be to use the addition assignment operator [+= Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7s8d7f4.aspx):

```
proov += 1
```

Another way is to explicitly add 1 to the value:

```
proov = proov + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

As is already suggested multiple times, simply adding 1 will usually suffice:

```
proov += 1
```

But it's worth knowing that this can get you in trouble once you start writing multithreaded applications, because incrementing a variable is not an atomic operation:

1. Get the value from `proov`
2. Increment this value by 1
3. Store the new value in `proov`

If a thread `y` jumps in before thread `x` completes all 3 steps, thread `x` and `y` will end up doing the same thing.

To prevent that from happening, use the `Interlocked` class in the `System.Threading` namespace to `Increment()` the variable:

```
If myClientMachineIP.AddressFamily = Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
    Label2.Text = myClientMachineIP.ToString()
Else
    TextBox2.Text = "IP does not equal to IPv4"
    TextBox3.Text = Threading.Interlocked.Increment(proov)
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this:

proov++

or

```
TextBox2.Text = "IP does not equal to IPv4"
proov = proov + 1
TextBox3.Text = proov
```